# ツールボックスにPDFViewerが追加されない。

Tags: c#, windows, .net, pdf

今、Windowsのアプリを作っているのですが、
１点わからないことがあるので、質問させてください。(^^)

作っているのは、PDFの簡易ビューワみたいなものなのですが、
Pdfium.Net.SDK というパッケージがPDFの操作を可能にしてくれるそうなので、
VisualStudioからnugetで、このパッケージを引っ張ってみたのですが、
dllは配置されたのですが、ツールボックスのコンポーネントに
PDFViewerみたいなコンポーネントが追加されるらしいのですが、
これが追加されなくて困っています。
原因として何か考えられることなどありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下の方法いずれかをお試しください。

→やりかた1
(1)Nugetでpdfium.NET.SDKを導入する。
(2)ソリューションを閉じる
(3)ソリューションを開く
(4)ツールボックスに「Patagames Pdf.Net SDK」のタブが自動的に追加され表示されている。

→やり方2
(1)ツールボックス画面の余白で[タブの追加]を選択→任意のタブ名をつける
(2)追加したタブを右クリック→[アイテムの選択]を選ぶ
(3)[.Net Frameworkコンポーネント]タブの画面で、右下[参照]ボタンを押す。
(4)ソリューションのフォルダ内の以下をたどる。[packages] > [Pdfium.Net.SDK.4.1.2704] > [lib] > netXX > Patagames.Pdf.WinForms.dll　を選択して[開く]
(5)名前空間「Patagames.Pdf.Net.Controls.WinForms～～」にて選択できるツールボックスアイテムが表示される。

Comment: [公式](https://pdfium.patagames.com/downloads/) が載せてる動画にて、アイテムの選択の手順を説明していました。